# Can't find the actual problem in find greatest of three numbers python code

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to find greatest number among three .

```
a = int(input('Enter number of a :- '))
b = int(input('Enter number of b :- '))
c = int(input('Enter number of c :- '))

if a>b or a>c :
    print(a)
elif b>a or b>c:
    print(b)
elif c>a or c>b:
    print(c)
```

It's working perfectly . But whenever I put the greatest number in c it doesn't work . It shows the greatest number among a and b .

Comment: Your condition is the problem, you should change `or` to `and`. You could also use `max` function and pass it `a` `b` and `c`

Comment: @DavidS , Thank You , I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `and` instead of `or`.

```py
a = int(input('Enter number of a :- '))
b = int(input('Enter number of b :- '))
c = int(input('Enter number of c :- '))

if a>b and a>c :
    print(a)
elif b>a and b>c:
    print(b)
elif c>a and c>b:
    print(c)
```

And further, the code can be optimized by avoiding some of the conditions.

```py
if a>b and a>c :
    print(a)
elif b>c:
    print(b)
else:
    print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because between the two arguments in your **conditions** you write **or** and if **b** is greatest than **a** but smallest than **c** the condition is **True** and the code return the **b** number, then replace ***or*** by ***and***.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for what you are trying to achieve is using `max()`.

```py
a = int(input('Enter number of a :- '))
b = int(input('Enter number of b :- '))
c = int(input('Enter number of c :- '))

print(max(a,b,c))
```